# change button text and state by click and show list in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have one button in front each list item when I click on the watched button, I want the text of the button to be changed to not watched(or when click on not watched it change to watched) and to be included in the watched list. At the top, I have three buttons, watched and not watched , which one I clicked on. Show me the list of the movies that I changed, their state and for third button(with text of all )it shows the whole list.I think that my problem is handleWatchedBtn function . this is picture of project maybe it is simple my explanation! thank you for your help.
[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const App = () => {
  const [Movies, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [Keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [OverSeven, setOverSeven] = useState(false);
  const [filterByWatch, setfilterByWatch] = useState("ALL");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/bemaxima/fake-api/movies")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setMovie(
          response.map((item) => ({
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
            rate: item.rate,
            watched: false,
          }))
        );
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  function handleWatchedBtn(id) {
    setMovie(() =>
      Movies.map((movie) => {
        if (movie.id === id) {
          return { movie, watched: !movie.watched };
        }
        return movie;
      })
    );
  }

  function handleWatchedChange(filter) {
    setfilterByWatch({ filterByWatch: filter });
  }

  function handleKeywordChange(e) {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleOverSevenChange(e) {
    setOverSeven(e.target.checked);
  }

  function filterItems() {
    return Movies.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(Keyword.toLowerCase())
    )
      .filter((item) => (OverSeven ? item.rate > 7 : true))
      .filter((item) =>
        filterByWatch === "ALL"
          ? true
          : item.watched === (filterByWatch === "WATCHED")
      );
  }
  if (Loading) {
    return "Please wait...";
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          Keyword
          <input type="text" value={Keyword} onChange={handleKeywordChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("ALL")}>all</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("WATCHED")}>watch</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("NOT_WATCHED")}>
            not watch
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          Only over 7.0
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={OverSeven}
            onChange={handleOverSevenChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {filterItems().map((movie) => (
              <li data-id={movie.id}>
                {`${movie.name} ${movie.rate}`}{" "}
                <button onClick={() => handleWatchedBtn(movie.id)}>
                  {movie.watched ? "Watched" : " Not watched"}
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a new array state which stores all filtered movies and is updated every time the movies or the filter are updated.
You can then pass its reference to the `map` function that generates the list.
Also, notice that I've added the spread operator (...) in the `handleWatchedBtn` function and adjusted the `handleWatchedChange` method to update the state to a string and not an object.

Try to change your code like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [Movies, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [filteredMovies, setFilteredMovies] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [Keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [OverSeven, setOverSeven] = useState(false);
  const [filterByWatch, setfilterByWatch] = useState("ALL");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/bemaxima/fake-api/movies")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        const newMovies = response.map((item) => ({
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name,
          rate: item.rate,
          watched: false,
        }));
        setMovie(newMovies);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update filtered movies when the data or the filter changes
    const newFilteredMovies = Movies.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(Keyword.toLowerCase())
    )
      .filter((item) => (OverSeven ? item.rate > 7 : true))
      .filter((item) =>
        filterByWatch === "ALL"
          ? true
          : item.watched === (filterByWatch === "WATCHED")
      );

    setFilteredMovies(newFilteredMovies);
  }, [Movies, filterByWatch]);

  function handleWatchedBtn(id) {
    setMovie(() =>
      Movies.map((movie) => {
        if (movie.id === id) {
          // Add the spread operator here
          return { ...movie, watched: !movie.watched };
        }
        return movie;
      })
    );
  }

  function handleWatchedChange(filter) {
    // Change this line
    setfilterByWatch(filter);
  }

  function handleKeywordChange(e) {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleOverSevenChange(e) {
    setOverSeven(e.target.checked);
  }

  if (Loading) {
    return "Please wait...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          Keyword
          <input type="text" value={Keyword} onChange={handleKeywordChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("ALL")}>all</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("WATCHED")}>watch</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleWatchedChange("NOT_WATCHED")}>
            not watch
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          Only over 7.0
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={OverSeven}
            onChange={handleOverSevenChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {filteredMovies.map((movie) => (
              <li data-id={movie.id}>
                {`${movie.name} ${movie.rate}`}{" "}
                <button onClick={() => handleWatchedBtn(movie.id)}>
                  {movie.watched ? "Watched" : " Not watched"}
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```